# Python TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this piece of code:

```
if current_ins[0] == "REPEAT":
    for i in range(current_ins[1]):
        if last_ins != "":
            instructions.append(last_ins)
            if delay != -1:
                instructions.append(["DELAY", delay])
        else:
            print ("ERROR: REPEAT can't be the first instruction")
            sys.exit(-1)
```

and unfortunately I get this error:

```
Duck Encoder 0.1.1 by Roger Serentill & GoldraK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\devloc\Encoders-decoders\USB-Rubber-Ducky-master\Encoder\Encoder.py", line 379, in <module>
    p.compile(sys.argv)
  File "D:\devloc\Encoders-decoders\USB-Rubber-Ducky-master\Encoder\Encoder.py", line 56, in compile
    instructions = self.__read_file()
  File "D:\devloc\Encoders-decoders\USB-Rubber-Ducky-master\Encoder\Encoder.py", line 263, in __read_file
    for i in range(current_ins[1]):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What can I do?

BTW, i'm using Python3.

Comment: What does `current_ins[1]` contain? Possibly, it could be a string containing a number and it needs to be converted: `range(int(current_ins[1]))`

Comment: Thanks! range(int(current_ins[1])) works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try `range(len(current_ins[1])):` or `range(int(current_ins[1])):`. It depends on what is inside current_ins[1].

Comment: Thank you! range(int(current_ins[1])): works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to make something like this:-

```
Inst1
Inst2
REPEAT 5
```

Now you are trying to repeat previous instructions whatever the "number" you have specified with Repeat.

You can sure just covert it to int, e.g. `int(currenct_inst[1])`, but that's really ambigous. According to the `zen of python` i advise you to be more explicit, perhaps

```
if current_instruction[0] = repeat:
    # strip here removes the leading and trailing whitespace
    times_repeat = int(current_instrucitons[1].strip())
```

If you would like to handle a instruction like `REPEAT (::)`, then you should take a look at exception handling.

If you're interested, take a look at:-
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling